# Blazor wasm completely refreshes when going back or forward

Tags: blazor-webassembly

So I'll admit my blazor WASM knowledge is pretty amateur right now - I've only begun investigating its potential for my projects but one thing has struck me as especially weird and poor: if you use the browser's back or forward buttons it completely refreshes the app. The splash screen comes back up and all state is lost. Is this intended behaviour? And is there any way to get back/forward to just use the blazor router so the user doesn't get this jarring interrupt in the UX/UI?

Comment: No, it is not intended behaviour. It's better to show your code to identify the issue.

Comment: Frankly I don't know what code I could share. Except for adding in additional pages and changing the formatting of the layout and whatnot not much has changed from the startup template. Program.cs is the same, app.razor is the same.

Answer (score 1):

It was by design,if you want to keep current statue, you could store it in somewhere else,for example In-memory state container service

A minimal example in a default blazor webassembly template:

```
public class CounterStateContainer
    {
        private int Count;

        public int CurrentCount
        {
            get => Count ;
            set
            {
                Count = value;
                NotifyStateChanged();
            }
        }

        public event Action? OnChange;

        private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    }
```

register it in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CounterStateContainer>();
```

another counter component:

```
@page "/newcounter"
@inject CounterStateContainer counter


<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>NewCounter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @counter.CurrentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        counter.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        counter.CurrentCount++;

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        counter.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

When I debug:
[image]

For more details, you could check the document related with [Blazor state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#in-memory-state-container-service)

Comment: The question isn't asking about state but a full page refresh

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I realise I made an error in the initial question mentioning state, I was using that a bit too liberally. Anyway, I did not realise that only navigations undertaken using a  element would allow back/forward browser navigations to work seamlessly.